# Parsing huge tables in tables with skipping?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm developing an android application that parses json and looks for two of the same words.
For the current day.

But i'm just asking now for the best way to parse all that HTML code into Json.
So [this site](http://www.rsgrijks.nl/Groepenrooster%20internet/GroeHTML_V2A.htm) is in dutch. But I'll try to guide you a bit,

The top table says `Maandag` through `vrijdag`, which translated, are the days (Monday to Friday) from left to right.

I need to skip these cells. Also the cells from that say: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 from top to bottom.

But now! The cells from the 'main' table has a table in it. So a table in a cell.
I only need the third cell from the table in the cell.

So for example:

At "Vrijdag", "1" It says: "L119"

I only need to have these **together** with the day and number.
so that is probably gonna be a 3D array json.

I can do further explanation if needed.

But for a conclusion:
I need a way to parse the classrooms ( ex. "L119", "D60", "S-5", "C162" ) together with the day and numbers on the left into a 3D json array.

It would be awesome if you could send the *the source code* but If you do so please also provide some simple explanation. I will also put your name in the credits if you want. But it will be a Dutch app.

Answer (score 0):

NVM I got it myself.
If you wonder how i did it:

I used something called: "Simple_HTML_Dom.php" I used this to find the right table and content!

***-Tim***

Comment: True, but you could also ask the one who made the schedule in Untis export it to an easier readable format.